# Adding entities/attributes to CoreData in a live app

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

I have finally published my first App, and am now looking to make improvements from user feedback.

The app uses CoreData with existing schema entities and attributes. I am looking to add additional attributes to existing entities, and add some new entities.

My question is, can I simply make changes to the CoreData schema then publish the app's update? Is there any migration process I need to be aware of? What do I need to consider as the impact on existing app users?

I vaguely recall reading many months ago that I should "version control" CoreData? Though I might be completely wrong.

Comment: Look into lightweight migration and model versioning, also test, test and test.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn’t remember or find any of these terms. If you could add your comment as an answer I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into lightweight migration and model versioning, also test, test and test.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_lightweight_migration

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

This is also a really good article
https://www.grantgrueninger.com/2020/01/nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-in-production/

I emphasize sending an update with just the core data changes before the code that actually uses the changes to prevent inconsistencies when the user has 2 devices.